# In R how to select rows from a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column "Year" in my dataframe ("import") and I need to only select 2015 out of some 30 years. However none of the steps I tried worked. Things I tried include:

```
iy2015<-subset(import, import$year==2015)
iy2015<-import[which(import$year==2015),]
iy2015<-import[import$year==2015,]
```

all have given me an empty dataframe.

Comment: According to your comment on the answer below, you are using `$year` when it should be `$Year`.  This is a typo and should be closed as such.

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to Year and it worked.

Comment: Don't use the df name and $ when using `subset` and noting that you say its name is "Year", then DO pay close attention to spelling. Try: `iy2015<-subset(import, Year==2015)`

Answer (score 1):

For me your last option works, check if 2015 is in the column and check whether year is a column name. I used: `iy2015 = import[import$Year==2015,]`

**EDIT:**

You need to use Year instead of year.

Comment: again I am getting an empty dataframe... here are results after I ran str(import)

Comment: 'data.frame': 3809 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Flow   : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
 $ Country: chr  "Afghanistan" "Afghanistan" "Afghanistan" "Afghanistan" ...
 $ Trade  : num  6.53e+09 7.72e+09 7.70e+09 8.55e+09 6.20e+09 ...
 $ Year   : num  2016 2015 2014 2013 2012 ...

Comment: Does `import$Year==2015` give a sequence with only one TRUE value?